# How do I delete an entry from Firefox address bar autocomplete?

Tags: macos, firefox

Because the site won't let me comment on an existing post, I am required to duplicate it.

> Delete does not work, shift+delete does not work. It's frustrating to
> have old misspelled addresses constantly pop up and have no way to
> remove them. I constantly go to the wrong pages.

Since near all the replies/solutions consist of "it works for me" I'm going to reiterate what was said by @felwithe by saying

> It doesn't work for me

There is clearly something that prevents the shift-delete method from working for some users.

HW: Macbook Pro 13-inch 2016 [the keyboard's 'delete' key is actually 'backspace' and 'fn-delete' replicates the 'delete' keyboard function.] 
OS: MacOS 11.1 
Firefox: 84.0.2

After partially typing the undesirable url, the keyboard arrow keys are used to highlight the undesirable url and the following methods are attempted to remove the individual undesirable url, followed by the results in square brackets.

**Has functionality**

M1: **del** [*last letter in url is deleted*] 
M3: **shift+del** [*last letter in url is deleted*] 
M5: **cmd+del** [*entire url is deleted*] 
M7: **cmd+shift+del** [*entire url is deleted*] 
M9: **opt+del** [*last segment/word in url is deleted*] 
M11: **opt+shift+del** [*last segment/word in url is deleted*] 
M27: **ctl+opt+shift+del** [*last segment/word in url is deleted*]

**Does not have functionality**

M2: **fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M4: **shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M6: **cmd+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M8: **cmd+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M10: **opt+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M12: **opt+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M13: **opt+cmd+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M14: **opt+cmd+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M15: **opt+cmd+shift+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M16: **opt+cmd+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M17: **ctl+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M18: **ctl+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M19: **ctl+shift+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M20: **ctl+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M21: **ctl+cmd+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M22: **ctl+cmd+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M23: **ctl+cmd+shift+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M24: **ctl+cmd+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M25: **ctl+opt+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M26: **ctl+opt+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M28: **ctl+opt+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M29: **ctl+opt+cmd+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M30: **ctl+opt+cmd+fn+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M31: **ctl+opt+cmd+shift+del** [*nothing happens*] 
M32: **ctl+opt+cmd+shift+fn+del** [*nothing happens*]

From this I can ascertain that, **with my installation**

1. [shift] has no effect
2. [fn] negates all function
3. [ctl] negates all function **except** in method M27

Additionally, the results were identical in Firefox safe mode (restart with add-ons turned off)

Further Testing 
T2: I used Microsoft Remote Desktop to connect to a VM running Windows 10 and Firefox 83.0 
M3: **shift+del** [cached url removed as desired]

I don't know enough about how modifiers are implemented in MacOS, Windows or Firefox to figure out how to fix this behavior, but I am hoping someone here does.

Comment: revisiting this: now using MacOS 11.3.1 and Firefox 97.0.1, shift+delete works as expected.  I am unaware of which version this was fixed in, or if it was macOS or Firefox.